Can landlord prevent tenant from installing window air conditioning in NYC?
In a standard non rent stabilized apartment in Brooklyn NYC, is a tenant allowed to install a standard window air conditioning unit, assuming it won't block any fire exits, and assuming it's safely installed?
Even if there is a clause in the lease like:

Tenant shall not install a waterbed, laundry machine, dishwasher, refrigerator, sink, kitchen cabinets, stove or other
mechanical equipment or an antenna, in or outside the Apartment, without the written consent of the Landlord.

Is it enforceable absolutely? Not everything mentioned in a lease must be enforced.
If not then what is a tenant expected to do in extremely hot summer months? A fan is not enough.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Short Answer
The best argument would be one to compel the landlord to use some form of cooling to make the apartment habitable, rather than arguing for a right to address the problem yourself.
But it would be a long shot to convince a court that an apartment wasn't habitable in New York City, unless it was much hotter in the apartment than it was outside. Employing your own self-help solution by installing a window air conditioner without landlord permission is a high risk gambit that is unlikely to succeed.
Long Answer
The answer by Trish correctly states that: "Contract clauses are enforceable unless they violate the law."
The Warranty Of Habitability
The most obvious possible law that might be violated is the warranty of habitability. In New York State, this is codified at NY Real Prop L § 235-B (2023) and it states:

§ 235-b. Warranty of habitability.

In every written or oral lease or rental agreement for residential premises the landlord or lessor shall be deemed to covenant and
warrant that the premises so leased or rented and all areas used in
connection therewith in common with other tenants or residents are
fit for human habitation and for the uses reasonably intended by the
parties and that the occupants of such premises shall not be subjected
to any conditions which would be dangerous, hazardous or detrimental
to their life, health or safety. When any such condition has been
caused by the misconduct of the tenant or lessee or persons under his
direction or control, it shall not constitute a breach of such
covenants and warranties.

Any agreement by a lessee or tenant of a dwelling waiving or modifying his rights as set forth in this section shall be void as
contrary to public policy.

In determining the amount of damages sustained by a tenant as a result of a breach of the warranty set forth in the section, the
court;


(a) need not require any expert testimony; and
(b) shall, to the extent the warranty is breached or cannot be cured
by reason of a strike or other labor dispute which is not caused
primarily by the individual landlord or lessor and such damages are
attributable to such strike, exclude recovery to such extent, except
to the extent of the net savings, if any, to the landlord or lessor by
reason of such strike or labor dispute allocable to the tenant's
premises, provided, however, that the landlord or lesser has made a
good faith attempt, where practicable, to cure the breach.
(c) where the premises is subject to regulation pursuant to the local
emergency housing rent control law, the emergency tenant protection
act of nineteen seventy-four, the rent stabilization law of nineteen
hundred sixty-nine or the city rent and rehabilitation law, reduce the
amount awarded hereunder by the total amount of any rent reduction
ordered by the state division of housing and community renewal
pursuant to such laws or act, awarded to the tenant, from the
effective date of such rent reduction order, that relates to one or
more matters for which relief is awarded hereunder.

New York City's protective landlord-tenant laws don't really change the statewide standard, although there is a proposal to change the law:

There is no legal right for air conditioning in New York City. . . .the Adams administration proposed mandated cooling in new construction
by 2025 and setting a maximum indoor temperature by 2030 — something
Dallas has already done, setting 85 degrees as the max.

(Source)
Remedies
If the apartment is really so hot that living there is "detrimental to the life, health, or safety" of the tenant, then the remedy would be to sue the landlord for not providing the minimal air conditioning or other cooling necessary to make the apartment habitable, rather than to provide that cooling yourself.
A possible settlement would be for the landlord, cognizant of the various legitimate concerns related to electricity supply, equipment quality, mounting, and landmark preservation resulting in the lease term, rather than the tenant, to install some form of cooling for the unit.
Alternately, the landlord could provide vouchers for motels or Airbnb type accommodations on those days when it is forecast to be so hot that the apartment isn't habitable. Or, the landlord could force you to do that and you could sue the landlord for the money damages you incurred as a result.
Landlord Incentives
The landlord has a strong incentive to make life for tenants in rent stabilized apartments as miserable as possible consistent with the law, however, because if you end your lease voluntarily, or breach your lease, the landlord can charge fair market value rent for that apartment, which is often twice as high as what you are paying, to a new replacement tenant in the unit. So even a landlord who is personally somewhat sympathetic to your plight has a strong incentive to be as unreasonable as possible when it comes to making your life in the apartment comfortable, for example, by giving you permission to install a window air conditioner in your unit.
Self-Help
To avoid breach of lease liability, one would probably have to show that:

the warranty of habitability was breached by the landlord,

you at least made a reasonable request for the landlord to take action,

no action of taken within a reasonable period of time, and

as a result, you were mitigating your damages for the landlord's breach of the implied warranty of habitability.


In those circumstances, the cost of the air conditioning mitigation might even be awarded to you if the court found that there was a breach of the implied warranty of habitability.
Avoiding a finding that you breached the lease is a high stakes issue in New York City in a rent stabilized apartment. These apartments rent for much less than fair market value rent, so if you lose, you are not only evicted, your monthly rental costs will also go up dramatically, forever, costing you many hundreds or even thousands of dollars a month indefinitely. On average, a rent stabilized apartment in New York City reduces a tenant's rent by $18,000 a year.
So, the risk of being found to have violated the lease because while it was uncomfortably hot, it didn't violate the implied warranty of habitability, or you didn't give the landlord an adequate opportunity to address the issue, makes self-help an extremely risky option.
Even if it got very hot on a particular day, the landlord could argue that you should have mitigated your damages by going to a free city cooling center, rather than by breaching the lease. Given that probably fewer than twelve days a year are dangerously hot in any given New York City summer, a judge or jury might find this argument to be convincing.
It would usually make more sense in terms of cost and risk considered together to stay in air conditioned motels or hotels on hot days as a form of self-help than to risk breaking the lease by installing your own window air conditioner. This expense could be awarded to you as damages if a court found that your landlord breached the implied warranty of habitability. But, you wouldn't risk breaching the lease and losing your rent stabilized apartment in the process.
Indeed, since the temperatures in the evenings usually are habitable, finding some place to stay part-time during the hot parts of the day might even be sufficient. For example, a three month gym membership at a location with air conditioning might cost $450 a year or less. Nightly low temperature in New York City in July average just 68ºF, which even with high humidity is very tolerable, and while it would be warmer on the hottest days, it would still probably be well under 85ºF.
How Hot Is Too Hot?
The hard question is how seriously the landlord and the courts would take the claim that it is intolerably hot during the hottest days of the summer.
Certainly, at some indoor temperature, e.g. 120ºF, you would have a winning case. But where would a court draw the line? 85ºF? 90ºF? 100ºF?
It is impossible to know in advance and factors like whether the tenants were senior citizens, who are more vulnerable to heat, or not, might factor in as well.
The cutoff would, realistically, also be influenced by the fact that you agreed to rent an apartment without air conditioning in New York City, whose climate is a matter of public record, which would normally command a higher rent. This would be a factor even though it doesn't directly enter into the legal standard, which is "habitability", because a court is likely to distinguish between "habitability" and "comfort." About 14% of people in Brooklyn don't have air conditioning.
Some of the better precedents might be cases where state prisons were required to install some form of cooling. For example, an in cell temperature of 112ºF is the basis of a currently pending lawsuit against prison wardens in Texas, with temperatures in cells routinely exceeding 100ºF in 70% of Texas prisons. The suit seeks a rule requiring temperatures to be between 65ºF and 85ºF in cells.
Evidence regarding safe temperatures for people for sustained periods of time, for example, from public health agencies or from building codes, would also be powerful. For example, according to an article at Live Science:

With climate change causing temperatures to rise across the globe,
extreme heat is becoming more and more of a health threat. The human
body is resilient, but it can only handle so much. So what is the
highest temperature people can endure?
The answer is straightforward: a wet-bulb temperature of 95 degrees
Fahrenheit (35 degrees Celsius), according to a 2020 study in the
journal Science Advances. Wet-bulb temperature is not the same as the
air temperature you might see reported by your local forecaster or
favorite weather app. Rather, a wet-bulb temperature is measured by a
thermometer covered in a water-soaked cloth, and it takes into account
both heat and humidity. The latter is important because with more
water in the air, it's harder for sweat to evaporate off the body and
cool a person down.
If the humidity is low but the temperature is high, or vice versa, the
wet-bulb temperature probably won't near the human body's tipping
point, said Colin Raymond, a postdoctoral researcher at NASA's Jet
Propulsion Laboratory who studies extreme heat. But when both the
humidity and the temperature are very high, the wet-bulb temperature
can creep toward dangerous levels. For example, when the air
temperature is 115 F (46.1 C) and the relative humidity is 30%, the
wet-bulb temperature is only about 87 F (30.5 C). But when the air
temperature is 102 F (38.9 C) and the relative humidity is 77%, the
wet-bulb temperature is about 95 F (35 C).

In NYC in 2018 the data for outdoor "dry bulb" temperatures was as follows:

Average humidity in New York City in July when temperatures are at their peak at 4 p.m. ranges from 53%-63%, which implies a wet-bulb temperature of about in a worst case 63% humidity scenario of a wet-bulb temperature of 95ºF at a dry-bulb temperature of 107ºF.
The hottest day ever in NYC history was when LaGuardia reported 107 °F (42 °C) on July 3, 1966, which is right at the threshold for the maximum temperature in which a human being can live.
It is certainly possible for indoor air temperatures to be hotter than outdoor air temperatures, however, with the most common example being inside a car with the windows closed.
Proof
Of course, as a factual matter, the tenant would also have to reliably and credibly establish the indoor air temperature on each of the days that the tenant argues were unreasonable hot in the apartment.

Whie there might be a right to have some sort of cooling installed or not depending on the temperature of the building on hot days, that does not give a right to violate the clause "you have to inform the landlord and get permission to install other mechanical equipment" - Sure, you have a right to a habitable flat, but you don't have the right to install the HVAC without permission (e.g. the landlord might be compelled to agree to a reasonable solution within building code guidelines)

@Trish Generally I'd agree, but it the landlord was breaching the lease's implied warranty of habitability, the argument that you are merely mitigating damages might work at that point.

With a huge if on the habitability, I agree. For NYC, that might be a hard sell.

"because if you end your lease voluntarily, or breach your lease, the landlord can charge fair market value rent for that apartment". Do you have a source for this? AFAIK post-2019 this is only true for J-51 units built before 1974, since for 421-a (or J-51 units built/gut-renovated after '74) when the tax abatement ends the units would become market-rate on renewal of the lease anyway.

@kopecs It was true for the bulk of my 1995-the present legal career. Is it possible that this has been partially reformed in the last four or five years? Sure. I don't follow NYC rent control laws very closely. This said, the mentality has seeped itself deeply into NYC landlord culture and even if there have been reforms since then, landlords themselves may not have fully assimilated this reality yet.

Contract clauses are enforceable unless they violate the law. "Don't install things that might cause damage on your own" is very much legal and enforceable. Here the examples are mostly water-related (sink, waterbed, laundry machine, dishwasher), but also heavy electricity users (fridge, laundry machine, dishwasher, stove) or large-scale renovations (kitchen cabinets, all the appliances). Besides those, there's a clause on "other mechanical equipment" and "antenna".
The question here is: is a window AC unit falling under the envelope of those "other mechanical equipment"? This is unclear and would require clarification by the landlord. It does not matter if the item sticks out of the window or not, the term "other mechanical equipment" can encompass anything from heavy tools to any other large or heavy installation. Often enough, the term "mechanical equipment" appears in building codes and can include or exclude HVAC or window AC units in different areas, and at times the time the unit is there is also relevant for if you require a permit or not.
For example, NYC defines for its code that a through-window AC unit is not mechanical equipment but an HVAC (and thus might or might not require a permit for an HVAC). Also, the Landmark Preservation Commission has something to say when you may or may not use a window AC.


HVAC equipment. The term "HVAC equipment" includes through-window, through-wall, rooftop, areaway, and facade and yard mounted heating, ventilation, and air conditioning equipment, including louvers, wall-mounted louvers and stove, restaurant, bathroom and/or dryer vents.
Mechanical equipment. The term "mechanical equipment" means equipment other than HVAC equipment, such as solar and wind power equipment, batteries and emergency generators, and including any associated elements such as safety railings and sound attenuation screens, baffles and other structures.


On the other hand, Liberty, Missoury defines:

30-72.10 UDO Design Principle: Mechanical and weather protection devices shall be
placed and installed in a manner that is unobtrusive
Portable window air conditioner units are
allowed in street-facing windows, as they are
considered temporary elements. However,
any window AC units that are to be installed
permanently, or that have been in place more
than 12 months, shall be subject to review by
the HDRC. Of greatest concern is that the
window frame is not damaged, and that the
unit does not allow water to enter the structure
or stand in any area.

In either case, getting written allowance for items that, if shoddily installed, might create an assortment of damage, is always advised.
For window AC units there are many possible damages the installation or improper installation could cause. Just of the top of the head, there's falling from the place, damaging the window frame, wall, or other mounting points, creating an ingress for rainwater for a bad seal against the window frame, springing a leak of its (toxic) coolant, overloading the electrical wiring in the building (which is a fire hazard), or if the unit is not secured in some way, it could be an entry point for burglars.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This answer addresses building code and zoning laws. The important factor here is rental laws. In many places in the US, lack of air conditioning would make a dwelling uninhabitable. NYC is perhaps the most regulated rental market in the nation.
